# How do I manipulate /tmp/audio in repl.it to play audio?

Tags: c++, audio, replit

While these docs are good ([documentation](https://docs.repl.it/repls/audio)), I seriously can't find any way to manipulate the files to play audio specifically in the c++ ide in repl.it. This isn't straightforward, and they only have a library for python, and node.js, so it requires me to go through the tmp/audio area.

Comment: What did you try doing?

Comment: I tried a pipe, and also tried inputting the code for the request they had on their site @user253751

Comment: They say /tmp/audio is a named pipe. Do you know how to open a named pipe? Hint: it's exactly the same as a file

Comment: how would I open a named pipe (as in code)? @user253751

Comment: hint: it's exactly the same as a file

Comment: I already did fstream audio, but now how do I properly send a request? @user253751

Comment: Maybe you write a request like the one shown in the documentation